# Exporting joined list from sharepoint to excel

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have two lists in sharepoint: one list is a customer list with customer id, name and state, the other is an order list that has a lookup column that refers to the customer id, order date and order amount.  I would like to join both lists on customer id and export the joined list to excel so that I can create a pivot table that, say, lists sales by state.

I'm able to create a linked datasource using the sharepoint designer.  I haven't been able to find a way to export that to excel however.  Can someone offer advice?

Regards

Comment: Did you consider export by javascript?

Comment: Nope.  How do I do that?

Comment: I'll see if I can post the solution tomorrow, it is a quite extensive solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by opening both lists in Excel.

Use Open in Excel button in the first list. It will open this list in Excel. Let Excel opened and use the same button in the second list. Excel will pop up dialog where you can choose how to open it. Choose table and new Sheet option.

After that you will have 1 excel file with 2 lists imported in it each on separate sheet.

Next step is using Relationships button in Data ribbon which allows you to join imported lists.

And the final step is to insert PivotTable (Insert - PivotTable). Use External data source option in Insert dialog - Choose Connection... button - Tables tab - and select joined table from previous step (This workbook data model section).

At the end you have Excel with Pivot table where you can drill down data using columns from both lists.